# jshint not making relations between files in chrome-extension

Tags: google-chrome, jshint

While working on my chrome extension, those two files are called by the manifest and there are dependencies between them. But jshint wouldn't mind.

Can I give my jshint a clue that my files are linked ?

```
app/scripts/background.js
  line 37  col 15  'WebSocketInterface' is not defined.
app/scripts/lib/wsi.js
  line 3   col 23  'WebSocketInterface' is defined but never used.
✖ 2 problems
```

Any better option than telling jsHint to discard this kind of errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file that uses `WebSocketInterface` (but doesn't define it) you can use a `global` directive. The `false` means JSHint will give a warning if you attempt to assign to `WebSocketInterface` (if you need to assign to it just use `true` instead):

```
/*global WebSocketInterface: false */
```

In the file that defines it but does not use it you can use an `exported` directive:

```
/*exported WebSocketInterface */
```